# How can I get a list of GA custom metrics and dimensions using HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get a list of custom metrics and dimensions from Google Analytics using
XmlHttpRequest.
However, I can’t find any via Google API reference. Please, suggest an
endpoint or any other way to get custom metrics.

Comment: Could you add the link using [ text ] ( url ) to the place where you looked at the reference. Adds credibility to your question.... and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 dimensions and 1 metric associated with custom dimensions and metrics avaliable though the Google Analytics API.  [Custom Variables or Columns - Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns)

The HTTP Get will look something like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:<ViewID>&start-date=2014-05-27&end-date=2014-05-27&dimensions=ga:dimensionXX,ga:customVarNameXX,ga:customVarValueXX&metrics=ga:metricXX&max-results=10000&&oauth_token=<AccessToken>
```

Now the main problem you will have is that `XX` is the number of the Custom variable you want to select.  There is no way to get back a list of custom Dimensions and metrics a user has set up for the account.   There is a feature request for it though: [Expose custom Var (Dimensions and metrics)](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=422&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

Work around a user can max have 20 custom dimensions and 20 custom metrics (unless its a premium Google Analytics account and then the limit is 200).  So a way to do this would be to send a request 1 - 20 now if the user doesn't have something set up for that custom dimension or metric then it will just return nothing no problem.

The call is to the Core Reporting API you can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide)

Hope this helps.